# How to display more than one display by a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, display

I need to know IF a Raspberry Pi can drive more than one display at a time,
and if it can, WHERE can I find more info on how to do this?

I want to eventually drive six(6) separate displays. Not to, say, stream a different movie on each one of the 6, but I would like to learn theoretically if I can drive all 6, each with a different software-generated animation at what I expect will be smaller resolution

Comment: This was a 3 minute google: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/hdmi-config.md _On the Raspberry Pi 4 there are two micro HDMI ports, so you will need either one or two micro-HDMI-to-full-size-HDMI leads or adapters, depending on how many displays you wish to attach_

Comment: Thank you.

I perhaps should have elaborated on the question...I want to eventually drive six(6) separate displays. Not to,say, run a different movie on each one, but I would like to learn theoretically if I can drive all six(6), at expected smaller resolution. 

I am a noob, but just guessing, perhaps it would entail 5 or 6 satellite Arduinos.

Comment: Clarification: I want to eventually drive six(6) separate displays. Not to, say, stream a different movie on each one of the 6, but I would like to learn theoretically if I can drive all 6, each with a different software-generated animation at what I expect will be smaller resolution. 

I am a noob, but just guessing, but I suspect the R-Pi can handle the animation calculations. Then perhaps delivery to 6 _small_ screens might entail 5 or 6 satellite Arduinos. 2 HDMI ports won't do it. Or is there some bus technology, out of the R-Pi?

Comment: Maybe this will do what you but it's not clear whether it just duplicates the picture or splits it across multiple screens https://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/ it's a hardware solution but since the pi ony has two ouputs thats your only choice

Comment: This is probably a far better forum https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/